# IWebBrowser2->get_Document returns S_FALSE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, windows-8.1

```
IWebBrowser2* browser;
CComPtr<IDispatch> disp;
HRESULT hr = browser->get_Document(&disp);
```

In above code hr values after call to get_Document is S_FALSE but when I try to see error informaiton by using GetLastError it says error no =0.

This code is working fine on windows 7 but giving problems in windows 8.1

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give more information? What document is currently loaded? What's the URL? Does it contain ActiveX objects?

Comment: `GetLastError()` is useless in this case, you should try request `IErrorInfo`.

Comment: S_FALSE means the object was not safe for scripting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752116.aspx), so it's a security issue

Comment: already tried to make it work but its still not working.